# Umbraco: my new published package is missing on Developer section

Tags: package, umbraco, publish

I made new Package for Umbraco, then I publish it on http://our.umbraco.org/projects.
Now the package is online. It is available to community.

But I can't find it inside an Umbraco installation.
If I go in Umbraco backoffice, "Developer", "Packages", "Umbraco package repositories", I can't find it.

Why?
Maybe I will wait some days? The package is online since August 23, 2013.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote on Umbraco Forum as for suggestion of @ProNotion, then I received answer.

> Hi Flavio
>
> That's because packages needs to have 15 karma points before they're
>   available in the backoffice. It's that way to ensure that the packages
>   you can install directly from within Umbraco are high quality that
>   have been approved by the community.
>
> Cheers, Jan

Topic url:
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/44611-Umbraco-my-new-published-package-is-missing-on-Developer-section

Answer (score 0):

I think the package has to have a certain number of votes before it makes it into the Umbraco package repository. I don't believe that the exact rules are officially published anywhere so can't direct you somewhere for official confirmation other than to suggest you ask on the forums or Twitter with the hash tag #umbraco.

Comment: Thanks, I try. This is the topic: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/44611-Umbraco-my-new-published-package-is-missing-on-Developer-section